# Xcode swift random EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION for no reason

Tags: ios, xcode, exception, swift

I am getting random EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION errors in Xcode and it's driving me crazy.

Here is my class:

```
import Foundation
import BigInteger
import CryptoSwift

class NonceController: NSObject {

    func generateNonce(secret: NSString!, timeoutSeconds: Int) -> NSString {

        var nonce: NSString = ""

        println(secret.length < 10)

        var test: NSString = "testsasa"



        if test.length < 10 { // EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) thrown here

        }


        if secret.length < 10 {
            //INVALID, throw exception

        } else {
            //valid params
            var salt: BigInteger = generateSalt()


            var dateDouble = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970) * 1000

            var currentMillies: BigInteger = BigInteger(dateDouble)

            var maxTime = currentMillies + timeoutSeconds * 1000

            var maxTime: Int = Int(currentMillies + (Int(timeoutSeconds) * 1000))

            var toHash = "\(salt)\(secret)\(maxTime)"

            var hash: String = toHash.sha1()!.lowercaseString
            nonce = "\(salt),\(maxTime),\(hash)"
        }
        return nonce // If I remove the test length check it is thrown here instead
    }

    func generateSalt() -> BigInteger {
        ...

    }
}
```

If I remove that dummy test, the exception is thrown on the return line instead.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?? I think this is a bug with Xcode as these errors seem to throw randomly. I can use this code in other classes and it runs fine...

Cheers!

Comment: "I think this is a bug with Xcode" – as many, you seem to be confusing Xcode with the Swift interpreter/compiler. This would be a bug in Xcode if Xcode itself crashed. I suppose that it's your code instead that receives the `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` signal. While it has a higher chance than normal that the Swift interpreter/compiler is buggy (since it's a very young implementation), in general compilers tend to be extremely well-implemented and bug free. If your program crashes, it's usually your fault. So if I were you, before losing my humbleness and pointing to the compiler, I'd use a debugger.

Comment: You are importing a bunch of frameworks I've never heard of. Could they have something to do with it?

Comment: I have tested the same statements on files that still use those frameworks as imports and it runs fine. In fact, before the call to that function I run that exact length test and even that works. I have tried removing both frameworks from the project completely, problem persists. There seems to be no logical reason for this (my code side).

Comment: You are setting test to "testsasa" and then checking for test.length < 10 and never using test again? What is the real code you are trying to run?